# Internal Server Error 500 In Angular 6 Node js application deployed in Azure

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

[console snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8NUF.png)
I'm getting this error when I trying to browse the website. but these files are stored in the same directory and base href is set up for the same directory. Application runs fine in the localhost

Comment: did you set the proper Node runtime?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#create-a-web-app